# EditText field displaying data on different tabs

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm having some pretty strange issues with my app. I have an EditText element, lets call it display, in a reused fragment for each tab. Every time I launch the app I see the following initial behaviour when I click a button that sends text to the output display. I do not use the system keyboard, only my buttons send to the display.

The best way to think of this is like a web browser with tabs, you can edit the URL in each tab independently, and the buttons, that live below in the other two sections, supply the input. It's not a web browser, but the analogy works.

[image]

- Don't click on anything -> Text drawn in B tab
- Click on B -> Text drawn in C tab
- Click on C -> Text drawn in C tab
- Click on B -> Click on C -> App Crashes

I might be running into a fencepost error but I'm not sure. I can get text to draw in A's output but only after a click or two.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.container);

    midPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.function_container);
    topPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.top_container);
    midPagerAdapter = new midPageAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    midPager.setAdapter(midPagerAdapter);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    TabsAdapter topTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this,topPager);
    topTabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("1"), 
                          TopFragment.class, null);
    topTabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("2"), 
                          TopFragment.class, null);
    topTabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("3"), 
                          TopFragment.class, null);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab",0));
    }
}
```

And in my function that manages the tabs this is what I have:

```
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(Activity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                               int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();

        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++)
        {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag)
            {
                setActiveMap(i);
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my reusable fragment I have this for my OnCreate function.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_fragment, container, false);
    Foobar active = Container.getActiveMap();
    active.editLine = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.display);
    active.editLine.setCursorVisible(false);
    active.editLine.addTextChangedListener((TextWatcher) this);
    ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.display)).setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}
```

One question that would help me debug this is how can I debug EditText within a reused fragment in tabs? What data does an EditText widget use to distinguish itself from tab to tab? I've tried various .tostring()'s of functions without success.

The more ideal solution is a simple error you spot in this code. Thanks for your help.

We could have 3 separate fragments but they all are of the same configuration however that seems unnecessarily ugly.

Comment: *What data does an EditText widget use to distinguish itself from tab to tab?* - you should be able to answer that question yourself because, as you reuse that fragment(so I'm assuming the same instance), it would be your job to know in which tab you are. Overall your question is a bit unclear, it would be important to know the exception thrown when the app crashes(and the code from where is thrown).

Comment: EditText is held in the Foobar class. active is the currently used Foobar.

I think I've found the bug but I'm unsure how to kill it. I set setOffscreenPageLimit(2) and then when I launched the app it was drawing to the 3rd tab's display. So I'm following the wrong context? (correct term?) In the onTabSelected function, I setActiveMap. The map is correct because I continually see foobar object 1 follows tab 1 when button x is pushed. So somehow my tab focus has become bugged and follows the last rendered fragment.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment as I don't see why you do so it's not helpful at all. In my comment I've asked you if the green fragment represents a **single** instance across all tabs or you have an instance for each tab? If it's the later case then explain with code how do you get the proper reference. Also, in cases like this where the data get's connected with the last created fragment of a ViewPager it may worth checking any static fields that you may have(if any) in your fragments/classes.

Comment: I have a single fragment I'm creating across all tabs. I have planned on having an instance for each tab but I'm unsure if it's actually working correctly. I created 3 Foobar objects and store a number of variables in them, including my EditText that is supposed to hold the information for each tab. None of my fields in Foobar are static.

Comment: @Luksprog any other ideas on why when the app starts on the 1st tab my buttons send data to the 2nd tab and when I click on the 2nd tab, it sends them to the third? When the app does finally crash after clicking and typing in the 3rd tab, it crashes with a nullpointerexception when I EditText setText().

Comment: After playing around with it some more it would definitely appear there are at least two issues going on here. The first is my Foobar object doesn't create nicely. Secondly, there are some initial focus issues. Thanks for your help @Luksprog but I'm not sure there's much more you can suggest from your end. I appreciate your help.